# Android Facebook Graph API (Page-Feed) doesn't post on page

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Graph API to post on a Facebook Page, I got the access tokens and gave all the permissions needed such as public-actions and others and retrieved my page ID as well. My code seems to be working fine but my message does not get posted on the Facebook page wall. I have tried the same method with (me/feed) and it does post on my wall. However, when I post on my Facebook Page with /{page-id}/feed it doesn't work. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
post_on_page.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View v) {
            post_on_page.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("name", "Test Name");
            params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
            params.putString("link", "https://www.facebook.com/Integration-test-1768******9580/");
            params.putString("display", "page");

            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "17680******39580/feed",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Posted on wall",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();



        }
    });
```

Comment: any error/response? you need to start debugging. also, see if it gets posted as user. in that case, you are not using a page token. publish_actions is the wrong permission, check out the api reference about the correct ones.

Comment: I gave all the page permission, publish_actions is just one of them. No error at all! I tried playing around with the Graph API explorer but cant seem to find an answer. Please help me, I check we dont really need a permission to post on a public page, yet I cant post on it! There must be some other thing! If you have any ideas or answers please let me know! I really appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: why would you use ALL permissions? only use those you really need (which is manage_pages and publish_pages). there is always a returned message if something does not work.

Comment: check out the docs to find out how to get the result: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/

Comment: or that one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/interface/GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the same method with (me/feed) and it does post on my wall

That´s a clear indication of using the wrong Access Token. You are using a User Token, but you need to use a **Page Token** with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I obtained my page access token, I generated whatever fields I could. But how do I use that access token to be able to post on page? It still doesn't work.

Comment: you use it right where you add the token right now: "AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()"

Comment: read through the docs to debug the graphrequest if it still does not work. there MUST be an error message or any message.

Comment: okay I dont know how to supply my page access token to the AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() method so what I did was:
 AccessToken token= new AccessToken(getString(R.string.accesstoken),getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),getString(R.string.user_id),null,null,null,null,null);
and I put the page token in the string. Then i used the variable "token" instead of the method but it just crashes my app..I read everything, yet im so lost! :(

Comment: why not just replace the function with the page token?

Comment: How can I do that? like just paste the token instead of AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()?? Can you show me where you are saying I should add it?

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got it to work after getting a permanent page access token. You have my deepest gratitude for helping me. :D